# Calculating summation on integer numbers from $-\infty$ to $\infty$

Tags: summation

Does anyone know how to calculate the following summation, in which $a$, $b$ and $k$ are constant real numbers:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{k n +a}{\big((k n +a)^2 + b^2\big)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

In the above relation, $n$ is an integer number which changes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: What are $a$ and $l$ and $b$? Are they integers too?

Comment: yes, they are constant real numbers. @Nilknarf

Comment: Do you know how can one calculate it? @Nilknarf

Comment: No, I have no idea. Maybe try partial fractions?

Comment: Why did you delete your previous almost *same* question?

Comment: Because I decide to ask it in a simpler way. Could you hep? @JaideepKhare

Comment: After playing around with this a bit, I'm now sure that the result of this sum cannot be written in terms of elementary functions. If you're looking for a nice concise closed form result, there is no such thing. The answer would be related to Hurwitz zeta functions $\zeta(3/2, a+ib)$ and $\zeta(1/2, a+ib)$.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the answer in terms of Hurwitz zeta functions? Any answer concise closed or complicated can help me@Hamed

Comment: in Hurwitz zeta functions power of n is equal to zero but in my case, power is equal to 2. @Hamed

Comment: Where is $k$ in Hurwitz zeta functions you wrote?

Comment: Also, the function is not defined for s=1/2

Comment: I said a "variation" of Hurwitz. First off, you can factor $k$ out of the sum, so $k$ doesn't really matter all that much (rescale $a\to a/k$ and $b\to b/k$). Hurwitz zeta is $\zeta(s,q)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1/(n+q)^s$. What you need is two slight variations of it $\zeta_1(s,q)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1/|n+q|^s$ and $\zeta_2(s,q)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+q)/|n+q|^{s+1}$. Point is, although niether of these sums are Hurwitz zeta itself, you cannot write them via elementary functions either. Note that these sums all are absolutely convergent to the same value $\zeta(s,q)$ absolutely converges to.

Comment: Do you know any good approximation which may help to find the value of the summation? @Hamed

Comment: If you're looking for a good approximation, you should consider posting another question. I'm sure there are people infinitely better than me when it comes to approximating sums.